# Efficient way to keep track of duplicate files uploaded by various users

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, storage

I am designing a file management system where users can upload their files to 'folders' on our server. In reality, the files are uploaded to s3 and I maintain the hash of the file as key for storage. This helps in avoiding duplication in storage in cases when different users upload a similar file to different folders. The catch is in the delete part. When a user deletes a file, there is no guarantee for a safe delete of the file from s3, since I use hash as key and this same file could have been uploaded by multiple users. How do I tackle this issue? How can I manage deletes and at the same time avoid redundancy by storing the same file multiple times?

This should make the problem more clear :

```
+----+-----------+------------------+----------------------------------+
| id | file name |      folder      |             md5 hash             |
+----+-----------+------------------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | file1     | /storage/folder1 | e2fc714c4727ee9395f324cd2e7f331f |
|  2 | file2     | /storage/folder1 | 1f7690ebdd9b4caf8fab49ca1757bf27 |
| 3  | file1     | /storage/folder2 | e2fc714c4727ee9395f324cd2e7f331f |
+----+-----------+------------------+----------------------------------+
```

If there is a request to delete file1 from /storage/folder1, I cannot remove the file from storage since it is present in /storage/folder2.

I can always check in my database if the hash of the file to be deleted is present in the hash column of any other row. But is this scalable when the number of files to be maintained grow in the order of millions?

Or do I maintain a different table that maps from hash to number of files with the same hash. This number increments by 1 during upload and decrements by 1 during delete. When the count reaches zero, the file can be safely removed from storage (s3).

Do these workarounds sound overly complicated? Or should I just go ahead and store every file irrespective of duplication and be done with it? How are things done usually in enterprises?

Comment: Consider using a hash of the combination of user ID and file.  Assuming the user ID is always unique, then you would likely never generate the same object key for the same file, per user.

Comment: I think you have to separate the file itself and references to it. So you have the file and some references in the folders to the file. If there are no more references you can delete it. Similar to your count version.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen which means we are still duplicating files in storage. Is that the industry norm?

Comment: There are a lot of things going on here.  First, do you have any statistics on how often a file would be getting duplicated?  If it's only a small percentage of data being duplicated, say < 5%, then I wouldn't even do any engineering; just store everything.  Another issue is a legal one.  If you only store one version of the file, if something happens to it, then all "owners" take a hit.  Your business model may not allow for this.